# "Cross Join" 2 queries

Tags: mysql

I have 2 queries:

I wish to display the results of these queries side by side(i.e. count for Nov and count for Dec):

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
      count(playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid) 
  FROM 
      playsms_tbluser 
    LEFT JOIN 
      playsms_tblsmsoutgoing
    ON 
      playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid = playsms_tbluser.uid 
   AND 
      MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11 
   AND     
      YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 2015 
 WHERE 
      playsms_tbluser.flag_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY 
      playsms_tbluser.name`
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
      count(playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid) 
  FROM 
      playsms_tbluser 
    LEFT JOIN 
      playsms_tblsmsoutgoing
    ON
      playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid = playsms_tbluser.uid 
   AND 
      MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 12 
   AND
      YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 2015 
 WHERE 
      playsms_tbluser.flag_deleted = 0 
GROUP BY 
      playsms_tbluser.name`
```

Is it possible? If yes how? I will be googling for solutions in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an alias for each table and then join it together using some id, in sample query below I will use `playsms_tbluser.name` as comparison for both table.

```
SELECT nov.name, countNov, countDec FROM
(
    SELECT playsms_tbluser.name, count(playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid) as countNov
    FROM playsms_tbluser LEFT JOIN playsms_tblsmsoutgoing
    ON playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid = playsms_tbluser.uid 
    AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 11 AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 2015 
    WHERE playsms_tbluser.flag_deleted = 0 
    GROUP BY playsms_tbluser.name
) as nov
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT playsms_tbluser.name, count(playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid)  as countDec
    FROM playsms_tbluser LEFT JOIN playsms_tblsmsoutgoing
    ON playsms_tblsmsoutgoing.uid = playsms_tbluser.uid 
    AND MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 12 AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(p_datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')) = 2015 
    WHERE playsms_tbluser.flag_deleted = 0 
    GROUP BY playsms_tbluser.name
) as dec ON nov.name = dec.name
```